# cannot filter with $match a node by another subnodes value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb4.0

environment: Mongo 4.2.2. invoking from Compass 1.20.5

I did `$unwind` 2 elements of an array (of a single document) into 2 single documents:

```
 {
    { id: 1 },
    { termTrg: { lang: "ara"} },
    { sublangTrans: { lang: "apj"} }
 }
```

and

```
 {
    { id: 1 },
    { termTrg: { lang: "ara"} },
    { sublangTrans: { lang: "ara"} }
 }
```

Before I `$group` them again by id 1 into one document, I wish to filter with `$match` documents where the lang attributes in a document are the same. Providing the string `ara` staticly, removes the second document as intended.

```
$match { 'sublangTrans.lang' : { $ne: 'ara' } }
```

If I try to replace the `ara` with the node's value of `termTrg.lang`, it does not remove any documents.

```
$match { 'sublangTrans.lang' : { $ne: 'termTrg.lang' } }
```

Why is `termTrg.lang` 's value not resolved? What is the correct syntax? Is there an alternative way to filter documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will match the string that is not equal to `termTrg.lang`

```js
$match { 'sublangTrans.lang' : { $ne: 'termTrg.lang' } }
```

To have get the resolved value of `termTrg.lang`, you have to use `$expr`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/

```js
$match: { $expr: { $ne: ['$sublangTrans.lang', '$termTrg.lang'] } }
```

In case you want to match items that have the same `lang` attrubute

```js
$match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$sublangTrans.lang', '$termTrg.lang'] } }
```